# Error in OptaPlannerBenchmarkAutoConfiguration fallback case for benchmark?

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, optaplanner

The following question refers to optaplanner version 8.24.1.Final:

In class OptaPlannerBenchmarkAutoConfiguration of package org.optaplanner.spring.boot.autoconfigure there is a fallback in line 61. 
Line 61 calls createFromSolverConfig in class PlannerBenchmarkConfig of package org.optaplanner.benchmark.config which in line 85 sets a single new SolverBenchmarkConfig for field solverBenchmarkConfigList of plannerBenchmarkConfig.
All fields in this SolverBenchmarkConfig are null.
Now moving further to line 93 of class OptaPlannerBenchmarkAutoConfiguration, there is a get on SolverConfig. But the field SolverConfig of the new SolverBenchmarkConfig described above is null. This throws a Nullpointerexception. 
Is this intentional? If yes, why? 

Admittedly it does seem a bit nonsensical to add the dependency of optaplanner-benchmark while not providing configuration for different solvers to benchmark, but then why even have this fallback? Am I missing something obvious?

Kind regards and thanks for your help!

Comment: How do we reproduce this problem? Sounds like a potential bug. If we can reproduce, we'll fix it.

Comment: Hello Geoffrey, thanks, I appreciate your effort! Simply letting OptaPlannerAutoConfiguration do its thing should reproduce the problem. In other words, creating a problem to solve (e.g. a Tsp-example) where we autowire SolverConfig and create SolverManager using the autowired SolverConfig to solve the problem. Then adding optaplanner-benchmark dependency should throw nullpointer